# WPF DataGrid.ItemsSource - set cell value without "Binding"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to set specific cell value in DataGrid, without use "Bindings" in XAML? Now i just refresh() whole list:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = speedList;
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

And it works, but not perfect... i mean it lagggs, soo much, because my list is probably too big and i need to refresh it once per second. I also tried:

```
dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid.Items[actualTarget], dataGrid.Columns[1]);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = speedList;
dataGrid.BeginEdit();
dataGrid.CommitEdit();
```

It worked better, because lags gone, but it focused that cell... I don't want that.

I saw other topics, where people did it on dataGrid.Items with Bindings in XAML, but I need to change my dataGrid structure onClick_Button - I have few Models.

Everything what I want is programmatically update one specific cell.

Comment: What you should be doing is find your item at `speedList[x]` and update the data value stored on that object. Providing property change notifications are correctly implemented and the datagrid is setup properly, it should automatically update without needing to do anything like reset the `ItemsSource` or call `.Refresh()`

Comment: I have very similar solution in other project... and it really automatically updated my cell. But now it update... only if i click 2 times on my cell (edit), then value is updated. Maybe because I tried do it in the background with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke... I dont know.

Comment: The Dispatcher could affect this. I'd suggest running at a different DispatcherPriority, one that runs before DataBind or Render. It might help if you have another question related to that, instead of this one. The best solution is to fix the timing of your update, instead of trying to find a bound DataGridCell and manually set its value. This most likely will not work because the grid is bound and probably uses Virtualization.

Comment: I removed dispatcher and tried do it in normal method without threads, but it still doesn't refresh automatically. I change something in my `ObservableCollection`. That `ObservableCollection` is  connected with `ItemsSource`. My cell is updated only if i click 2 times on it - first time while I enter to edit mode and second time while I leave from edit mode.

Comment: That is normal datagrid behavior - records switch to an Editing Template on click and usually only persist on LostFocus to prevent excessive saving to data source when doing something like typing in a TextBox. You can either write your own DataGridCellTemplate, or search about for other solutions - I'm sure it's a fairly common question to have single-click editing on a datagrid, or to change the binding most from the default LostFocus to something like PropertyChanged.